# How to groupby and calculate the average while ignoring "-" values in df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame like this, it is mixed with integer values and "-".

```
Manager  A  B  C  D
111      1  5  -  2
111      -  5  -  1
102      2  -  4  -
102      2  3  4  1
```

I am unable to use df.groupby(['Manager']).mean().round(2) as the df has "-" due to which i am gettign an error.
I want the output to be like grouped by manager id and with an average of columns A,B,C,D.

```
Manager  A  B  C  D
111      1  5  -  1.5
102      2  3  4  1
```

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: wow cant believe you changed your question again , I have deleted my answer just incase further edits come in the way..

Comment: I am sorry i am just learning stuff and kind of new to all this. i have tried the method you mentioned earlier everything was nan in the df after using that.

Comment: okay my last try would be `df.replace('-',np.nan).astype(float).set_index('Manager').mean(level=0).fillna('-').reset_index()`

Comment: It is giving me the mean of the managers also, can you please suggest ? the manager values like 15111409 are getting converted to something like 1.51036e+07